# Consulta eloquent no me trae el registro con el filtro especifico

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

He intentado hacer una consulta que me traiga todos los articulos que esten en estado **Activo** pero no he consiguido resultado alguno. Siempre me trae todos asi el estado este en inactivo y es lo que no qiero.

Estas son las consultas que tengo hasta ahora:

*Primera consulta*

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request) {
            /*obtener todos los registro de la base de datos de una determinada articulo
            trim:quita espacios*/
            $query = trim($request->get('searchText'));

            $articulos = Articulo::with(['categoria'])
                ->where('articulos.estado', '=', 'Activo')
                ->where('articulos.codigo', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')
                ->orwhere('articulos.nombre', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')
                ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
                ->paginate(2);
            return view('bodega.articulo.index', ["articulos" => $articulos, "searchText" => $query]);
        }
    }
```

---

*segunda consulta*

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    if ($request) {

        /*obtener todos los registro de la base de datos de una determinada articulo
        trim:quita espacios*/
        $query = trim($request->get('searchText'));

        $articulos = Articulo::with(['categoria'])
            ->whereIn('articulos.estado',['Activo'])
            ->where('articulos.codigo', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')
            ->orwhere('articulos.nombre', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%')
            ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
            ->paginate(2);

        return view('bodega.articulo.index', ["articulos" => $articulos, "searchText" => $query]);

    }
}
```

Las consultas las he realizado en Mysql y me funcionan. Tambien lo use con Query Builder de laravel y me funcion. Pero quiero saber como se consulta con Eloquent.

Comment: @AlfredoPaz Mira que realice la función anónima pero no me trae ningún registro.

Comment: @AlfredoPaz No me trae ningún registro..

Comment: @AlfredoPaz Esta bien, pero pues mientras me podrías dar un método directo de eloquent para mirar como me va.

Comment: Creo que el ->orwhere('articulos.nombre', 'LIKE', '%' . $query . '%') hace que te devuelva todos los activos O los que tengan el nombre como $query, estén o no activos.